# Push Notification can't Redirect to Mobile Web Home Page

Tags: firebase, push-notification

[my image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRWQD.png)

i made push notification for mobile web,
When trying to test using the Firebase console, a notification appears and when clicked it immediately redirects to the website's home page.
But when I test it using an application/service assistance such as Insomnia a notification successfully appears but when clicked it doesn't redirect to the home page website.

i tried using service-worker.js but it doesn't work when mobile chrome browser is minimized or closed